# Def Query to not display feature if it isn't attributed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, sql-server, definition-query

I have a bunch of features that I don't want to keep checking if something is attributed.  I I want to query it out to not show the geometry if a column has the default string 'NOT ATTRIBUTED' to it.

I can get it to run "Name = 'NOT ATTRIBUTED'" to work, but Name = NOT 'NOT ATTRIBUTED' doesn't work.

It won't run at all using the 'IS'  It has to use the equals sign.  It's on a SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be this?:

Name <> 'NOT ATTRIBUTED'

Comment: Yep, see the [Building a query expression](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002t000000) entry to confirm this: "The not equal (<>) operator can also be used when querying strings"

Comment: The syntax for not equal is as Stephen said "<>", or NOT NAME = 'NOT ATTRIBUTED'. The order of the operators is important.

Comment: Now it's saying that it passes verification, but no records have been returned.  And there are a lot of fields in the row that are attributed.

Comment: @joebob, do you have a domain set on database column?

Comment: Yes, There are domains on a few of the columns, but not all.

Comment: @joebob The only other thing I can think of is to make sure there are no extraneous "spaces" before, in the middle, or after the text string you are querying on. Use the Query Builder to build your query (i.e. avoid copy-and-paste).